# Prevent parent script from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke website.  Baked into the DNN code is the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    dnn.controls.submitComp.onsubmit();
    return true;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The problem is, I put a form on a page on my website that performs a search, and I wired up a jquery listener that says if the enter key is pushed, fire my button click event.  The problem is, the parent script above ALSO fires that WebForm_OnSubmit() function, and whatever that onsubmit() function\return true does is causing my page to just refresh.

So, if there anything i can do so "override" or "prevent" that WebForm_OnSubmit() function from also triggering?

---

Edit 1: In response to the question "how is your listener setup":

I have a function called canISearch:

```
function canISearch() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#btnSearch").click();
    }
}
```

and I fire this function using my onkeydown attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="txtblah" onkeydown="canISearch()" />
```

Comment: Do you want your form to submit every time the enter button is used? If not, why not submit it only when your form field is in focus?

Comment: Thanks @fgshepard the problem is that script at "Webform_OnSubmit()" function listens to all enter key presses.  So I can be on the webpage, just scrolling through content, and hit the enter key, and it fires - refreshing the page. So I need a way to prevent that function from firing, or at the very least ignore it if the user is within my search textbox.

Comment: is that function in the global space, i.e., available under window.Webform_OnSubmit?

Comment: The script tag with the function is within the head section of the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the dnn code in order for the method to do nothing when your function is present on the page:

```
dnn.controls.submitComp.onsubmit = function() {/*doing nothing, ladida*/};
```

Which may be a bit harsh since your modification can have an impact on other behaviors. You can instead add a method that checks that your control has focus before routing the code accordingly. This is most likely the simplest hack.

You could also prevent the event from bubbling up, as Brennan suggests; it really depends how events are attached. If I remember correctly DNN can intrude on your events in so many ways this may not be easy to do.

Or you could create your own skin in order to control all the components that are pushed onto the page and prevent the auto submit from the wrapping form.

Comment: The routing option is what I tried to outline above, although it looks like you have provided the proper way to access the method in question. I would recommend giving this a try.

Comment: @ewitkows Appreciate the feeling, will virtually partake from another continent ;)

Answer (score 2):

If WebForm_OnSubmit is in the global space, you can overwrite it and create an exception for your case. Sometime after the original function is defined, redefine it. Maybe something like this:

(NOTE: updated to incorporate information from Samy's answer below)

```
(function () {
    var originalFn = dnn.controls.submitComp.onsubmit;
    dnn.controls.submitComp.onsubmit = function() {
        if ([your element is in focus]) {
            ... do your thing ...
        } else {
            originalFn();
        }
    };
})()
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea conceptually, and in line with what im trying to do.. but it doesn't work :(  window.WebForm_OnSubmit is returning undefined =-\

Comment: Would it be possible to link to a sample page?

Comment: Does samy's answer below perhaps provide the correct way to target this function? i.e., use
     dnn.controls.submitComp.onsubmit
in place of 
     window.WebForm_OnSubmit
?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @fgshepard, your idea was right on point, it was just how to access the function in question, which I coudldn't figure out. samy's idea was able to resolve the issue, thanks again!

Comment: ewitkows you can also upvote the answer if you feel like multiple answers are valuable. To be honest, I hadn't understood fgshepard idea when I answered and was thinking more about javascript hacks: +1 for being on the right track

Answer (score 1):

How is your listener set up? You should be able to stop propagation of the event to keep it from moving up the event hierarchy:

```
$(".element").keyup(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Brennan, just added the code as you recommended, but still same result.  Please see my updated answer..